# Assign, and set js object property conditionally

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```js
app.post('/ujfeladat', (req, res) => {
    const {nev, tipus, szid} = req.body;
    const hianyos = () => {
        if(tipus === 'hianyos'){
            return {rang: -1}
        }
        return
    }
    db('fl').insert({
        nev: nev,
        tipus: tipus,
        szid: szid,
        hianyos() //returns an error
    }).returning('*')
    .then(data => res.json(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

How can i do that to add the `rang` property to the object only if the `tipus === 'hianyos'`?

Comment: Are you fine if rang exists with undefined stored or you don't want anything related to rang

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Updated answer:

**Here's how you can do it**:

```js
// Will result in { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}
const item = {
  foo: 'foo',
  ... true && { bar: 'bar' },
  ... false && { falsy: 'falsy' },
}

console.log(item)
```

**Explanations:**

Short-circuit evaluation (`true && {}`, `false && {}`) would return an `Object` or a `Boolean false` value.

In the case an `Object` is returned, its properties get spread and assigned to the parent object.

In the case `false` value is returned, the parent object isn't polluted, because ES6 treats `false, undefined, null and etc` values as `{}`. Therefore spreading `...{}` won't assign any properties to the parent object. More details about this, you can find [here.](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45#issuecomment-301973086)

---

## Original answer:

**Here's how you can do it**:

```
db('fl').insert({
  nev: nev,
  tipus: tipus,
  szid: szid,
  ...tipus === 'hianyos' ? { rang: -1 } : {}
})
```

**Explanations**:

As you can see the ternary operator always returns an **object**.

If the condition is *true*, then it returns `{ rang: -1 }`, otherwise an empty object `{}`.

After that we spread out `...` the resulted object (from the ternary operation) and the object's properties are assigned to the parent object.

If there aren't any properties, then nothing will be assigned, which is our goal.

**Code example:** (*sometimes few lines of code better than a thousands of words*)

```js
// Will result in { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}
const item = {
  foo: 'foo',
  ... true ? { bar: 'bar' } : {},
  ... false ? { falsy: 'falsy' } : {},
}

console.log(item)
```

In other answer I explained the same idea, but for arrays. You can check it too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771259/4312466).

Comment: wow!! 2 years ago, you wouldn't even recognize that as javascript :p

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But can you please tell the name of this syntax?

Comment: @GeraszHorváth you can check the details. Feel free to ask :)

Comment: Only the spread was the unknown element, but i did read about it, it's very useful, but i don't really understand it yet because of the many possible use form of it. Obejcts, arrays, functions, and all have different meanings. Thanks for the answer again, it helped me a lot!

Comment: this is great however doesn't work for ... i guess babel... was giving me an error about non iterable array... But still awesome for non-transpiled js :) thanks

Comment: Hmm. @carinlynchin thank you for the feedback! Maybe you have to consider checking https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread