# Set onClick if onClick prop given

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that might or might not recieve an `onClick` prop. I want to attatch this non-required prop as a click handler.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    let {onClick} = props;

    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}></div>
    );
}
```

Whats the safest way to do this sort of thing if I don't know if the handler will be given?

Answer (score 4):

Using spread and ternary operator:

```
const MyComponent = ({ onClick, ...rest }) => {
  const props = onClick ? { onClick } : {}

  return <div { ...props } />
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually have other props in this component. I just took them out to simplify the question. How would I do this when theres other props involved?

Comment: In `rest` variable, you have all others props.

Comment: Also if you want explicitly describe the props as we did it for onClick, you can define them conditionally as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367186/4312466

Comment: Can I just do this instead? `onClick = onClick || null` then set the `onClick={onClick}`?

Comment: I'm not sure whether setting a `null` handler will cause an error.  If so, you can pass an empty function, but in both cases you're setting a value to `onClick`. So I prefer the way I answered you.