# Is there any way to depend presence of key in Object on external value?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, key, computed-properties

I want to set some keys in object depending on flag value

For example

```js
const ourFlag = true //true or false depends on case

const ourObject = {
  name: 'Pablo',
  secondName: 'Picasso',
  [ourFlag && 'age']: 20,
  [ourFlag && 'moreComplexValue']: [
    {
      val: true
    },
    {
      val: false
    }
  ]
}
```

As long as `ourFlag` is set to `true` everything works as I expected, but when I change it's value to `false` some weird things started to come.

property `age` is no longer present - good
but property `moreComplexValue` is now `false`

Code I get when flag is `false`:

```js
{
  name: 'Pablo',
  secondName: 'Picasso',
            // age disappear as I expected
  false: [  //why!?!
    {
      val: true
    },
    {
      val: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Code I get when flag is `true`:

```js
{ .    //brilliant everything is fine
  name: 'Pablo',
  secondName: 'Picasso',
  age: 20,
  moreComplexValue: [
    {
      val: true
    },
    {
      val: false
    }
  ]
}
```

It's any way to handle it with that computed properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign, and set js object property conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367085/assign-and-set-js-object-property-conditionally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[flag && key]` evaluates to `false` or `key`, and this is exactly what your literal does, converting `false` to a string and overwriting it when the flag is false.

A better option would be to use an object spread `...flag && object`, which will expand to the object in the true case, and to an empty `Boolean` in the false case, thus essentially skipping it.

```js
let ourFlag = true

const a = {
    name: 'Pablo',
    secondName: 'Picasso',
    ...ourFlag && {age: 20},
    ...ourFlag && {moreComplexValue: [1, 2, 3]}
}

ourFlag = false


const b = {
    name: 'Pablo',
    secondName: 'Picasso',
    ...ourFlag && {age: 20},
    ...ourFlag && {moreComplexValue: [1, 2, 3]}
}

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Comment: isnt it a dupe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367085/assign-and-set-js-object-property-conditionally

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the javascript object keys are always strings and are typecasted to strings when otherwise.

So, it becomes string "false" when the value is `false` and the same key is used twice and rewritten with the second value

To set the keys dynamically, you could set it to undefined or set it with if..else

```
const ourFlag = true //true or false depends on case

const ourObject = {
  name: 'Pablo',
  secondName: 'Picasso',
}
if(ourFlag) {
  ourObject.age = 20;
  ourObject.moreComplexValue = [
    {
      val: true
    },
    {
      val: false
    }
  ];
}
```