# conditional object as array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the following:
In React, I have a component where a prop takes an array with objects, whereafter that component displays these objects in a dropdown menu item.
I would like to make some of thesedropdown menu items conditionally. In other words: some users may see a dropdown item, where others won't.

What is the correct way to achieve this? I tried using the spread operator (according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908159/how-to-define-an-array-with-conditional-elements), but I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
<Dropdown
    type="link"
    itemsObject={
       [...states.all.map(state => ({
           value: state.name,
           onClick: () => {
               this.updateCandidate(candidate, {state_id: state.id})
           }
        })),
        {
            isDivider: true
        },
        {
            value: "Notities bewerken",
            onClick: () => {
                this.openCandidateModel(candidate)
            }
        },
        ...(candidate.state.id === 2 ? [{
                value: "Afspraak beheren",
                onClick: () => {
                    this.openCandidateModel(candidate)
                }
           }] : undefined)
    ]}
/>
```

Comment: well, I guess if your ternary operator results in `undefined` it cannot be spread. Try wrapping undefined in brackets: `[undefined]` or using `[]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to spread `undefined` when `candidate.state.id !== 2`. Change it to:

```
...(candidate.state.id === 2 ? [{
                value: "Afspraak beheren",
                onClick: () => {
                    this.openCandidateModel(candidate)
                }
           }] : [])
```

Also, it's probably worth mentioning that `{...undefined}` is valid but `[...undefined]` isn't: [Spreading undefined in array vs object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155141/spreading-undefined-in-array-vs-object)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot spread `undefined`, but you can spread an empty array:

```
 [...undefined] // doesnt work
 [...[]] // works
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to spread undefined that is causing the error. Use ? [{}] : []

Answer (score 0):

```
   ...(candidate.state.id === 2 ? [{
            value: "Afspraak beheren",
            onClick: () => {
                this.openCandidateModel(candidate)
            }
       }] : undefined)
```

I believe the problem should be in this part as you can't spread undefined you can use empty array instead [ ].

Thanks!