# Typescript: how to properly type this conditional array function?

Tags: typescript

I wanted to define some arrays with conditional elements but wasn't satisfied with approaches outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908159/how-to-define-an-array-with-conditional-elements), so I created a helper function to make the declaration cleaner. The helper function is simple enough in vanilla JavaScript, but I've been having trouble typing it due to issues with generics.

**JavaScript version**

```js
const nin = Symbol('nin')

const includeIf = (condition, item) =>
    (typeof condition === "function" ? condition(item) : condition) ? item : nin

const conditionalArray = (init) =>
    init(includeIf).filter(item => item !== nin)

/* USAGE */

const cond = false

// should equal ['foo', 'bar', 'qux'] and have type string[]
const arr1 = conditionalArray(addIf => [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    addIf(cond, 'baz'),
    addIf(word => word.length < 10, 'qux')
])

// should equal [{ name: 'Alice', age: 23 }] and have type { name: string, age: number }[]
const arr2 = conditionalArray(addIf => [
    { name: 'Alice', age: 23 },
    addIf(false, { name: 'Bob', age: 34 }),
    addIf(person => person.age > 18, { name: 'Charlie', age: 5 })
])
```

**Updated TypeScript Version** with help from [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)

```js
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};

const nin = Symbol('nin')

type AddIf = <T, U>(condition: ((x: T) => boolean) | boolean, itemIfTrue: T, itemIfFalse?: U | typeof nin) => T | U | typeof nin
const addIf: AddIf = (condition, itemIfTrue, itemIfFalse = nin) => {
    return (typeof condition === "function" ? condition(itemIfTrue) : condition) ? itemIfTrue : itemIfFalse
}

const conditionalArray = <T extends Narrowable>(init: (addIf: AddIf) => Array<T | typeof nin>) =>
    init(addIf).filter((item): item is T => item !== nin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can do for now:

```
const nin = Symbol('nin')

// T is the array element type    
const includeIf = <T>(condition: boolean | ((x: T) => boolean), item: T) =>
    (typeof condition === "function" ? condition(item) : condition) ? item : nin

// describe the shape of the callback
type Init<T> = (cb:
    (condition: boolean | ((x: T) => boolean), item: T) => T | typeof nin
) => (T | typeof nin)[]

// T is the element type of the array.  Accept an Init<T>, produce a T[]
export const conditionalArray = <T>(init: Init<T>) =>
    init(includeIf).filter((item: T | typeof nin): item is T => item !== nin)


const cond = true    
declare function generateWord(): string

// need to manually specify <string> below :
const arr = conditionalArray<string>(addIf => [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    addIf(cond, "baz"),
    addIf(word => word.length < 10, generateWord())
]);
```

The typings are essentially correct, but I can't seem to get the compiler to infer `T` from a value of type `Init<T>`.  I'm guessing the nested/circular types are just too much for it.    So instead of just calling `conditionalArray(addIf => ...)`, I have to call `conditionalArray<string>(addIf => ...)`, or else `T` gets the "default" value of `{}` and you get both errors and a too-wide array type `Array<{}>` as output.

Hope that's of some help, anyway.

---

Update: good call making the type of `init` only generic in the type of its return value; that seems to un-confuse the compiler enough for inference to work.

So here's the best we have for now:

```
const nin = Symbol('nin')

type IncludeIf = typeof includeIf
const includeIf = <T>(condition: ((x: T) => boolean) | boolean, item: T): T | typeof nin => {
    return (typeof condition === "function" ? condition(item) : condition) ? item : nin
}

const conditionalArray = <T>(init: (includeIf: IncludeIf) => Array<T | typeof nin>) =>
    init(includeIf).filter((item): item is T => item !== nin)
```

To address your issues:

```
const arr1 = conditionalArray(addIf => [
    addIf(true, 1), addIf(true, 'a')
]); // Array<1 | "a">
```

Are you sure this is too restrictive?  [There's a lot of machinery in TypeScript around trying to determine when literal types should be left narrow or widened](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  I think `Array<1 | "a">` is a perfectly reasonable type to infer for the value `[1, "a"]`.  If you want to widen it, you can tell the compiler that `1` and `'a'` are not meant to be literal:

```
const arr1 = conditionalArray(addIf => [
  addIf(true, 1 as number), addIf(true, 'a' as string)
])
```

If you really want to force the return type of `conditionalArray()` to always be widened, then you can use a conditional type like this:

```
type WidenLiterals<T> =
    T extends string ? string :
    T extends number ? number :
    T extends boolean ? boolean :
    T

const conditionalArray = <T>(
  init: (includeIf: IncludeIf) => Array<T | typeof nin>) =>
  init(includeIf).filter((item): item is T => item !== nin) as
  Array<WidenLiterals<T>>;

const arr1 = conditionalArray(addIf => [
  addIf(true, 1), addIf(true, 'a')
]) // Array<string | number>
```

That works, but it might be more complicated than it's worth.

---

Your next issue:

```
const arr2 = conditionalArray((addIf) => [
  1, 2, 3, addIf(true, 4), addIf(false, '5'), addIf(false, { foo: true })
]); // Array<number | "5" | {foo: boolean}>
```

How important is it to you that the compiler recognize when you pass a *literal* `false` as the condition in `addIf()`?  I would expect that in real world code you would never do this... if you know at compile-time that the condition is `false`, then you would just leave it out of the array.  Conversely, if at compile-time you're not sure whether the condition is `true` or `false`, then you should want a *type* like the above even if the *value* happens to contain only numbers.

However, again, you can force the compiler to go through such logic via conditional types:

```
const includeIf = <T, B extends boolean>(condition: ((x: T) => B) | B, item: T) => {
  return ((typeof condition === "function" ? condition(item) : condition) ? item : nin) as
    (true extends B ? T : never) | typeof nin;
}

const arr2 = conditionalArray((addIf) => [
  1, 2, 3, addIf(true, 4), addIf(false, '5'), addIf(false, { foo: true })
]) // Array<number>
```

That works, but again, it might be more complicated than it's worth.

---

UPDATE 2:

Assuming you want to forget about literal `false` and you'd like to keep the element type as *narrow* as possible in all cases, you can do something like this:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};

const conditionalArray = <T extends Narrowable>(
    init: (includeIf: IncludeIf) => Array<T | typeof nin>
) => init(includeIf).filter((item): item is T => item !== nin)

const arr1 = conditionalArray(addIf => [1, "a"]);
// const arr1: (1 | "a")[]
```

That's because having `string`, `number`, and `boolean` mentioned explicitly inside the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `T` gives the compiler a hint that a literal type is desired.

See [Microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) for more details about how and when the compiler chooses to widen or preserve literal types.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just added my current best attempt above. What you have is pretty close to what I've been playing around with. I was also getting `{}[]` as a type, then I switched it so now it's too specific. I think I may need some `infer` magic but I'm pretty unfamiliar with it

Comment: Updated to address the issues you have with your current best attempt (although honestly I would just leave it the way you have it).

Comment: I think you're completely right about passing a _literal_ `false`, there's no good use case for that. However, it looks like adding the conditional type to `includeIf` also widens the return type. My only concern with having literal types instead of wider types was that `conditionalArray((addIf) => [1, 'a'])` is typed as `(string | number)[]` whereas `conditionalArray((addIf) => [1, addIf(true, 'a')])` is typed as `(number | "a")[]` and I think those types should be consistent. Do you know why adding the conditional type also widens the return type?

Comment: Also instead of widening the types to make them consistent, do you know if it's possible to get `conditionalArray((addIf) => [1, 'a'])` to be typed as `(1 | "a")[]` without making it a readonly?

Comment: Updated again.  I linked the [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) in my answer so you can read about how the compiler decides when to keep literal types literal and when it widens them.  Frankly I don't know why the conditional `includeIf` changes things; probably you'd have to read the compiler code and/or step through it with a debugger to understand, or ask someone who's worked on the compiler (i.e., not me).  I feel lucky just to have some tricks to widen/narrow literals when it does the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in TypeScript (modules export/import removed)

```
const nin = Symbol('nin')

type includeIfFunc = (condition: boolean | ((item: string) => boolean), item: string) => Symbol | string;
type addIfFunc = (addIfFunc: includeIfFunc) => (Symbol | string)[];
type conditionalArrayFunc = (init: addIfFunc) => (Symbol | string)[];

const includeIf: includeIfFunc = (condition: boolean | ((item: string) => boolean), item: string): Symbol | string =>
    (typeof condition === "function" ? condition(item) : condition) ? item : nin

const conditionalArray: conditionalArrayFunc = (init: addIfFunc) =>
    init(includeIf).filter(item => item !== nin)

const cond = true

const arr = conditionalArray(addIf => [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    addIf(cond, "baz"),
    addIf(word => word.length < 10, "generateWord")
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if my question wasn't clear but I'm trying to have the `conditionalArray` function work with arrays of any type, not just strings

Comment: Do you want same type array of array containing mixed type variables?

Comment: I would like arrays of a single type to be properly typed and arrays containing multiple types to have a union type. ie `conditionalArray(addIf => [addIf(true, 1), addIf(true, 'a')])` should have type `(number | string)[]`