# Ternary operator return nothing

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

is there a way to return nothing for ternary operator I mean

```
const a = [ 0 ? { name : "example" } : null ]
```

when i print a = [null]

or:

```
const a = [ 0 && {name:"example"}]
```

a will be [false]

i expected that a = [] for case 1

Comment: `const a = 0 ? [{name: "example"}] : []`?

Comment: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908159/how-to-define-an-array-with-conditional-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could spread an (empty) array.

```js
console.log([...(0 ? [{ name : "example" }] : [])]);
console.log([...(1 ? [{ name : "example" }] : [])]);
```

Answer (score 4):

No. It isn't possible. You are going to get a value back.

If you conditionally want a value, then either make the decision outside the array or filter the null values out afterwards.

e.g.

```
const a = 0 ? [ { name: "example" } ] : [];
```

or

```
const a = [ 0 ? { name : "example" } : null ].filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: yes i solved the problem with your first suggestion but i wondered is there antoher way

Answer (score 1):

`null` is a perfectly valid array value in Javascript, as is `undefined`.

You can simply construct the array on demand...

```js
const a = 0 ? [{ name : "example" }] : [];
```

or if this is part of a larger array construction, use splats...

```js
const a = [
    'a',
    ...(0 ? [{name : "example"}] : []),
    'b'
];

console.log(a); //-> ['a', 'b']
```