# How to push elements in array based on the avilability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array

```
let availabilityArray = [currentYearAvailability, previousYearAvailability, previousLastYearAvailability]
console.log(availabilityArray)
```

when I Console, I can able to find what is available what is not available

```
const preAuthAvailabilityYears =
    [
      currentYearAvailability ? currentYear : undefined,
      previousYearAvailability ? previousYear : undefined,
      previousLastYearAvailability ? previousLastYear : undefined,
    ]
```

[image: Console]

I need only the availability years to be displayed in the array instead showing as undefined as third argument, If it is undefined i shouldnot should in array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define an array with conditional elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908159/how-to-define-an-array-with-conditional-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const preAuthAvailabilityYears =
    [
      currentYearAvailability ? currentYear : undefined,
      previousYearAvailability ? previousYear : undefined,
      previousLastYearAvailability ? previousLastYear : undefined,
    ].filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it out like that if you are not required undefined.

Option 1

```
const preAuthAvailabilityYears =
    [
      currentYearAvailability ? currentYear : undefined,
      previousYearAvailability ? previousYear : undefined,
      previousLastYearAvailability ? previousLastYear : undefined,
    ].filter(Boolean);
```

Option 2

```
const preAuthAvailabilityYears =
        [
          currentYearAvailability ? currentYear : undefined,
          previousYearAvailability ? previousYear : undefined,
          previousLastYearAvailability ? previousLastYear : undefined,
        ].filter( item => item);
```